# Declaration of mandoe_menu_walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) must be compatible with Walker::start_el(...)

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I've originally hard-coded menu links into the mega menu of [mandoemedia.com](https://mandoemedia.com) in order to achieve the icon and description of each link.

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to convert these submenus into menus I can add through Appearance > Menus while still maintaining the icons and descriptions.

I see through Screen Options I can add a `Description` to each menu item and a `CSS Class` which I can use as in image filename.

From [this page](https://kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output), I've created a custom plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Mandoe Mega Menu Helper
Description: Allows images and descriptions in mega menus
Author: Steve Doig
Version: 1.0.0
*/

class mandoe_menu_walker extends Walker {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        $prepend = '<strong>';
        $append = '</strong>';
        $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span class="mm-mm-subtext">'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

        if($depth != 0) {
            $description = $append = $prepend = "";
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/icon-' . $class_names .'" alt="' . $item->title . '" class="mm-mm-icon">';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $description.$args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}

?>
```

but when activating this plugin I receive an error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of mandoe_menu_walker::start_el(&$output,
> $item, $depth, $args) must be compatible with
> Walker::start_el(&$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = [],
> $current_object_id = 0) in /wp-content/plugins/mm-mega-menu-helper/mm-mega-menu-helper.php
> on line 10

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the function definition to

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args=[], current_object_id = 0)
```

and it activated okay.

Answer (score 1):

An entirely different approach.

nav menu item are stored in posts table, so you can technically attach a post_meta into it, even other data like nav item class already stored in post mata table. However this wasn't easy to do before.

but after 5.4.0 release, they have implemented hooks to easily do this.

Here's the full step

**Add Custom Meta box on Nav item**

```
add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', function( $id, $navItem) {

  wp_nonce_field( 'nav_menu_icon_nonce', '_nav_menu_icon_nonce_name' );
  $nav_menu_icon = get_post_meta( $id, '_nav_menu_icon', true );
  ?>
  <p class="field-nav-icon nav-icon description-wide">
    <label for="edit-menu-item-nav-icon-<?php echo $id ;?>">
      Nav Icon<br>
      <textarea id="edit-menu-item-nav-icon-<?php echo $id ;?>" class="widefat edit-menu-item-nav-icon" rows="3" cols="20" name="menu_item_nav_icon[<?php echo $id ;?>]"><?php echo esc_attr( $nav_menu_icon ); ?></textarea>
      <span class="description">Add icon on menu.</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <?php
}, 10, 2 );
```

There should be another box in nav item after adding the code above like this
[image]

**Then save the value of that field into post meta**

```
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu_item', function($menuId, $menuItemId) {

  // current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) is a wordpress role which ensure the user can post unfiltered html
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['_nav_menu_icon_nonce_name'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_nav_menu_icon_nonce_name'], 'nav_menu_icon_nonce' ) || !current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) 
    return $menuId;
    
  if ( isset( $_POST['menu_item_nav_icon'][$menuItemId]  ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $menuItemId, '_nav_menu_icon', $_POST['menu_item_nav_icon'][$menuItemId] );
  } else {
    delete_post_meta( $menuItemId, '_nav_menu_icon' );
  }
}, 10, 2 );
```

and thats it, you now have additional data connected to each menu item for nav icon that supports text and html, you can add html tag like `<img />` for adding image as menu icon, or `svg`,

To display on the front-end, this depends on your set-up and where you want them to show

an example below that modify the nav menu item title via `nav_menu_item_title` filter and include the icon using `get_post_meta` to pull the icon value

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', function( $title, $item) {
  
  if( is_object( $item ) && isset( $item->ID ) ) {
    
    $navIcon = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_nav_menu_icon', true );
    
    if ( ! empty( $navIcon ) ) {
      $title = '<span class="icon">'.$navIcon.'</span>' . $title;
    }
    
  }
  return $title;
  
}, 10, 2 );
```

and the title would show the svg icon if there is

[image]